# jsp page request without servlet

Tags: java, jsp

I need to make a list in jsp with data from a database. The list is somewhere at over 45000 rows and make the browser very slow. Is any way to send a parameter from the same jsp in the html tag?

```
<td>
    <input type="text" name="nm">                                                        

    <select <% tfd = new CustomerFromDatabase(request.getParameter("nm")); %> 
        <%  
            Iterator tertiIterator = tfd.getTerti().entrySet().iterator();
            while(tertiIterator.hasNext()){
                Map.Entry<String, String> entry = (Map.Entry) tertiIterator.next();
                %><option value="<%= entry.getValue() %>"><%= entry.getValue() %></option>
        <%  }
        %>
     </select>
</td>
```

When I am initiating the CustomerFromDatabase object, I need to send the as parameter the value from the input "nm", so the retrieved list will contain less rows.

Can you help me with?

Thank you

Comment: Can you specify what "nm" contain?

Comment: Read some tutorials on the basics of HTML forms. You have to submit a form before the value from the input can be read by request.getParameter.

Comment: You can go for ajax here.Based on the input received,send an ajax request to server and populate dropdown.

Comment: Hi, You are right, I have changed the code as "<script>
            function fFN(){
                <%CustomerFromDatabase tfd = new TertiFromDatabase(request.getParameter("nm"));%>;
            }
        </script>  " and call this function on the button <> but nothing happens.